# Accessing 'Details' component of ADF activity run instead of 'Output'

Tags: azure-data-factory

ADFv2 seems to be allowing accessing Output of an activity using @('activityname').output but in the monitor we also see a 'Details' component for certain activity types (e.g. HDInsightHive, SQL etc), so is there any way we can access it? It contains very valuable information and it would be great if there is a way to access it somehow. The ADF drop down (adding dynamic values) obviously doesn't show it. This internally available information if exposed via UI would be a great plus.

The following screenshot shows how the detail window appears, basically one has to click on this yellow highlighted icon:-

[image]

Comment: Where did you see the `Details` in the monitor ? Providing some screenshot would be better.I just want to make sure that the `Details` window as same as yours'.

Comment: added in the post

Comment: yes,that's what i want to share with you. So,what's the issue here?I'm still confused your concern.You want to view this details in other place?

Comment: as far as 'Output' is concerned we can pass output of one activity as expression to any other activity in the same pipeline using @('activityname').output. But the same can't be done for 'Detail'. My question is not about viewing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now maybe i know your concern.You just wonder whether information could be accessed in the `Details` window. For example,my test copy activity:

[image]

Actually,based on my observation, the information listed in above window are exactly information in the error output.No more additional monitor information,just more readable and clear.

[image]

Besides,we can't find any more object of Activity Run Response from [REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/datafactory/activityruns/querybypipelinerun#activityrun).

[image]

So,if you are interested in the details info,please refer the output object.